# How to get the cover photo of each facebook album using facebook android sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cover

I am using facebook android sdk for accessing facebook albums. I've got the json that contains all the albums object. Want to get the cover photo of each album.
This is the object:

```
 "id": "3486732467234",
 "from": {
    "name": "Persons Name",
    "id": "Persons ID"
 },
 "name": "Vacation",
 "location": "City",
 "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=434235&id=324343&aid=2430",
 "cover_photo": "3489234432",
 "privacy": "everyone",
 "count": 60,
 "type": "normal",
 "created_time": "2007-06-03T23:01:16+0000",
 "updated_time": "2011-03-18T19:46:43+0000",
 "can_upload": true
```

}
 How can i get the cover_photo image with this value  "cover_photo": "3489234432" ??
I am able to get this value in a string..

Thanks

Comment: By looking up the photo ID on the Graph - https://graph.facebook.com/4346234652025?access_token=…

Answer (score 0):

just request photo info by photoID, use this API:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/photoID
```

Don't forget the access_token